# Quadratic Sieve on the Gaussian Integers

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization, gaussian-integers

Factoring a large Gaussian integer $z_0 = a+bi$ into Gaussian primes may be done by first factoring the norm $N(z_0) = a^2 + b^2$ over the integers, and then considering the factors of each integer prime (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269810/whats-a-nice-method-to-factor-gaussian-integers)).

However, this doubles the length of the integers involved in the problem. Naïvely, it would be faster to directly run the quadratic sieve algorithm over the Gaussian primes; i.e. evaluate the polynomial $P(z) = (z + w)^2 - z_0$ on a region around the origin, where $w$ is the closest lattice point to $\sqrt{z_0}$. We may compute roots of $P(z)$ modulo each Gaussian prime in our factor base, and sieve to locate smooth values of $P(z)$. The rest of the algorithm proceeds as usual, by searching for a linear dependence between the corresponding exponent vectors.

The two things I can see going wrong are:

1. No fast algorithm to compute square roots modulo a Gaussian prime. However, this is a relatively small computation compared to the rest of the sieving process.
2. Lower probability of smoothness when compared to the integer case. I don't know of any results on this, but I would be surprised if a Gaussian integer of norm $r$ is less likely to be smooth than a regular integer of size $r^2$.

I have implemented this algorithm (very unoptimized) and it works for small test cases ($a, b \sim 20$ digits). Are there any results on the runtime complexity of this algorithm, and why does nobody seem to use it?

Comment: The suggested algorithm can probably not be improved significantly. Additionally, the factorization into Gaussian primes is of very little practical interest.